# Отключенный Button активен

Tags: angular, button, primeng

есть Button, который остается disabled пока не будет заполнены все инпуты.
Но он все равно остается кликабельным, т.е. на вид он не активен, но при нажатии событие происходит.
Как сделать так, чтоб событие происходило только когда Button будет активным ?

```
<p-button styleClass="p-button-raised p-button-success ml-2" label={{saveLabel}} icon="pi pi-save" (click)="addClick()" [disabled]="transForm.invalid"></p-button>
```

Answer (score 0):

не знаю насколько это нормально, сделал след образом, вроде получил то, что ожидаю:

```
(click)="transForm.invalid === false ? addClick() : ''"
```